# Conditional redirect with express / request-promise

Tags: node.js, express, request-promise

I am rather new with **express** together with the **request-promise** module,
and need to create a **service S**
that is called from **serverA**
and after **S** has asked **ServerB** for some additional info,
it **redirects** the request of **serverA** to **ServerC.**
Since I get a 
*Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.*
even though I do not add something by myself, I wonder someone could help me to get this workflow straight.

This is the code:
`

```
const express = require('express')
const rp = require('request-promise')
  ...

app.get('/dispatch', cors(), (req, res, next) => {

var options = {
   uri: 'https://ServerB/calc-something..',
   headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'its-me',
      'Data': data_from_serverA
   },
   resolveWithFullResponse: true, // Get statuscode
   json: true // Parse the JSON string in the response
};

rp(options) // Do request to serverB
    .then(function (response) {
       console.log(`ServerB responded with statuscode ${response.statusCode}`)
       // No error, so redirect original res 
       res.redirect('https://serverC/...') // error occurs here
       return next(response)
    })
    .catch(function (err) { 
        console.log(`ServerB responded with error ${err}`)
        return next(err) // send 500 to serverA
    })
})
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cors()` middleware is setting CORS headers.  This is causing the headers to be sent while your promise is resolving.

A redirect ALSO sends headers, and this is the issue.  A redirect sets a `location` header, but you've already sent the headers so that won't work.

The solution is to split your final middleware into two.  First, check to see if a redirect is needed and if so, do that.  Otherwise, set whatever data you need on the `req` object and handle this AFTER the cors call.

Your final route will look something like:

`app.get('/dispatch', checkRedirect, cors(), (req, res, next) => {
 //do something useful, or send your error
})`

The contents of your checkRedirect function will be pretty similar to what you have above. However, you do not pass data to the `next()` function.  That just passes control to the next middleware.  Instead, put any data you need on the `req` object and handle it in the final middleware, AFTER cors.  If all you are doing is setting a 500 error, you don't even need CORS for that.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I try to map that into code, but it seems my knowlegde is quite limited

I have created a checkResult(req, res, next) that does an http get to serverB, and saves the data to req.
That works, but in the call
app.get('/dispatch', checkRedirect, cors(), (req,res,next)=>{..
The res.redirect() is never called,
Can you please tell me how the functions should look like?

Cheers!

Comment: I have meant checkRedirect(..), not checkResult(..)!

Answer (score 1):

According to @Rampant 's answer,
this is how I did it with *request-promise* (rp):

```
function checkPrecondition(req, res, next){
    req.precondition = false
    rp({ method: 'POST',
       ...
    })
    .then((data) => {
       ...
       req.precondition = true
       next()
    })
    .catch((data) => {
       ...
       next()
    })
}
```

and in the *express* handler:

```
app.post('/query', checkPrecondition, cors(), (req, res, next) => {
      if(!req.precondition){
          res.status(400).send(JSON.stringify({status: 'insufficient'}))
          return
      }
      res.redirect('target.host')
})
```

Thanks for clearifying the *CORS* issue.